# Fail to bind to specific network interface on Linux

Tags: linux, curl, networking

=== Background stuff ===
I have two wired ethernet interface on my Debian 9 server, both of them have internet access but through different ISP. 
enp11s0 192.168.0.9 
eth0 192.168.2.2 
`iptables -L` and `iptables -L -t nat` is empty and accepts all incoming and outgoing. Here is my `route`:

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp11s0
116.xxx.xxx.0   192.168.2.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp11s0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0`

=== End of Background === 
I would like to let most traffic go through enp11s0 since the eth0 is metered, but few connection go through eth0 (e.g. 116.xxx.xxx.xxx). This works, **but when I try to let a program bind to a specific interface, it becomes weird**.
`curl icanhazip.com --interface enp11s0` gives my ip address which is expected, however `curl icanhazip.com --interface eth0` does not work. With `-v` flag here is the output:
`* Rebuilt URL to: icanhazip.com/
*   Trying 144.202.71.30...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Local Interface eth0 is ip 192.168.2.2 using address family 2
* Local port: 0
*   Trying 2001:19f0:6401:18fc:2709:e14e:21cd:4e41...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Trying 2001:19f0:5c01:1aed:dcdf:7e47:e74b:1197...
* TCP_NODELAY set`

And it just keeps repeating forever. I added `-4` flag and `Trying 2001:19f0:6401:18fc:2709:e14e:21cd:4e41` disappears, but it still doesn't work. **How do I fix eth0? Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

see this question and answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1148582/specify-a-network-interface-with-curl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for a good explanation about how what you are attempting with curl is not what is happenning with curl.

You are curling an external address from `eth0` via the server default gateway which is on the link `enp11s0` .  check that forwarding is enabled on the server.

You need to set up policy based routing.  depending on what traffic you wan't to send out `eth0`, look into `iproute2`, `ip rule`, and

```
/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I created an additional route policy for the second interface and everything just works like a charm!